# Suppress stored procedure result

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a parent procedure that calls a child procedure and I need to suppress the result of this child procedure from parent procedure **WITHOUT USE INSERT INTO EXEC** because I already used it in parent of parent procedure.
Is there any way to achieve this?

EXAMPLE:

Parent procedure:

```
CREATE TABLE #Table (Field INT,Field2 INT);
EXEC [ChildProcedure];
```

Child procedure:

```
SELECT * FROM EXAMPLETABLE
--OTHER OPERATIONS
INSERT into #Table  SELECT * from SOMETABLE
```

The thing is that my child procedure has a select inside that I can't avoid.
When I call my child procedure from parent procedure I get the select result but I want to suppress it because I only want the `INSERT INTO` part.

Comment: Maybe you could do something with set noexec on, haven't tried it but it might work

Comment: can you show your procedure ?

Comment: @JamesZ The thing is that I need to exec that child procedure but suppresing any select result. And I need to control this behaviour from parent. Thank you.

Comment: @N.Molderf Sorry I'm not allowed to post the procedure and its big to sum it up. Thank you

Comment: @Cristian Abelleira could you show something similar to your cause because i can't understand what exactly do you want? Or try to explain more detail

Comment: @JeremyC. my question specifies that I CANT USE INSERT INTO EXEC, so is not duplicate. Thank you.

Comment: Even with updates I can not understand the problem. Show us complete example where we can play around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot suppress the SELECT result of sub-SPs without `INSERT EXEC`.

If you can change your sub-SPs, add an optional parameter at the end, `@SlientExit bit = 0`

```
IF @SlientExit = 1
  RETURN
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this Child SP do anything else? E.g.: update some data?
Just thinking you could try using SET FMTONLY ON/OFF, but that would prevent SP from running; 
example:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE TEST_C
AS
SELECT 1 AS ID
go

CREATE PROCEDURE TEST_P
AS
SET FMTONLY ON
EXEC TEST_C
SET FMTONLY OFF
SELECT 2 AS ID
go

EXEC TEST_P
go
```

or perhaps using fake condition in the child SP; WHERE 1 = 2

Comment: Yes it does something else so i cant prevent the whole execution. Thank you.